# Swift Lazy Property Initialization Circular Reference Compilation Error?

Tags: swift, properties, closures, lazy-loading, circular-reference

Can anyone explain why the following code will result in a circular reference error while compiling?

```
class Foo {
    
    let closure: ()->()
    
    func someFunc() {}
    
    init(closure: @escaping ()->()) {
        self.closure = closure
    }
}

class Bar {
    
    lazy var foo = Foo { [weak self] in // Circular Reference error here!
        self?.foo.someFunc()
    }
}
```

However if I change it to:

```
class Bar {

    lazy var foo: Foo = {
        return Foo { [weak self] in
            self?.foo.someFunc()
        }
    }()
}
```

then there is no circular reference error anymore.

I'm confused why one would cause an error, and the other would not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Updated:

The circular reference is in the type inferencing: It's the fact that `foo`'s type depends on `self.foo`'s type, which depends on `foo`'s type, which depends on `self.foo`'s type etc..

Previous Answer:

I think I figured out the root cause here (Thanks to some of my coworkers!):

My coworker noticed that this code compiles fine, which points out it might be a type inference issue. I was being thrown off by the wrapping closure, which apparently has nothing to do with the real issue.

```
class Bar {
    
    lazy var foo: Foo = Foo { [weak self] in
        self?.foo.someFunc()
    }
}
```

I think the in order for the compiler to evaluate `Bar` it must do type inference on the property `foo`, which requires the compiler to evaluate the property initialization code.  However the property initialization code itself contains a reference to `self`/`Bar`, so in order for that code to be evaluated, `Bar` must be evaluated first.  And thus the circular reference.

Comment: No, I don't see where there's any "type inference" here. And the problem has nothing to do with the evaluation of Bar.

Comment: You're right, it's not got anything to do with Bar, I think it just has to do with foo's type, and self.foo's type.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
lazy var foo = Foo { [weak self] in
    self.foo.someFunc()
} //     ^^^
```

So you are defining `foo` in terms of `foo`. That's a circle. It's no different from saying

```
lazy var foo = self.foo
```

which is very obviously circular.

When you wrap the whole thing in a level of evaluation (the `{...}()` construct), the inner reference to `self.foo` is guaranteed not to be evaluated until later.

Comment: The type inferencing is actually one of the key steps in the circular reference.  If you try
`lazy var foo: Foo = self.foo` it compiles without error.  However, like you said: `lazy var foo = self.foo` DOES cause a compilation error.  `foo`'s type depends on `self.foo`'s type, which depends on `foo`'s type, which depends on `self.foo`'s type ... etc... so you can see the circular reference because of the type inference.

Comment: The inner reference had nothing to do with the Circular reference either.  It's because when defining the closure with the inner reference, I had explicitly declared the type of `foo: Foo`, which broke the circular reference.

Comment: I'm going to have to think about that one!